# How to get the manual for sefcontext in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

`policycoreutils-python-utils` is already installed but still sefcontext is not found as seen below.

```
[munish259272@munish259272example ~]$ ansible-doc sefcontext
[WARNING]: module sefcontext not found in: /home/munish259272/.ansible/plugins/modules:/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules:/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible/modules
```

EDIT :

My ansible version:

```
[munish259272@munish259272example ~]$ ansible --version
ansible [core 2.12.2]
  config file = /home/munish259272/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/munish259272/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/munish259272/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.9.10 (main, Feb  9 2022, 00:00:00) [GCC 11.2.1 20220127 (Red Hat 11.2.1-9)]
  jinja version = 2.11.3
  libyaml = True


[munish259272@munish259272example ~]$ ansible-galaxy search sefcontext

Found 1 roles matching your search:

 Name                       Description
 ----                       -----------
 linux-system-roles.selinux Configure SELinux

[munish259272@munish259272example ~]$  ansible-galaxy  install linux-system-roles.selinux
Starting galaxy role install process
[WARNING]: - linux-system-roles.selinux (1.5.6) is already installed - use --force to change version to unspecified


[munish259272@munish259272example ~]$ rpm -ql policycoreutils-python-utils-3.4-4.el9.noarch
/etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.selinux.conf
/usr/bin/audit2allow
/usr/bin/audit2why
/usr/bin/chcat
/usr/sbin/semanage
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/semanage
/usr/share/man/man1/audit2allow.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/audit2why.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/chcat.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/semanage-boolean.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/semanage-dontaudit.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/semanage-export.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/semanage-fcontext.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/semanage-ibendport.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/semanage-ibpkey.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/semanage-import.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/semanage-interface.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/semanage-login.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/semanage-module.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/semanage-node.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/semanage-permissive.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/semanage-port.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/semanage-user.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/semanage.8.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man1/audit2allow.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man1/audit2why.1.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man8/chcat.8.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man8/semanage-boolean.8.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man8/semanage-dontaudit.8.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man8/semanage-export.8.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man8/semanage-fcontext.8.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man8/semanage-ibendport.8.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man8/semanage-ibpkey.8.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man8/semanage-import.8.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man8/semanage-interface.8.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man8/semanage-login.8.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man8/semanage-module.8.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man8/semanage-node.8.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man8/semanage-permissive.8.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man8/semanage-port.8.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man8/semanage-user.8.gz
/usr/share/man/ru/man8/semanage.8.gz
```

Comment: What Is your version of Ansible? Do you have the collection `community.general` installed?

Comment: `policycoreutils-python-utils is already installed`

in which path was it installed?

Comment: Even if it not resolve the cause of the effect you are observing, for "_How to get the manual for `sefcontext` **from** Ansible_" and a first glance you could have a look into the module source [`plugins/modules/sefcontext.py`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/main/plugins/modules/sefcontext.py).

Comment: @CarlosMonroyNieblas i have given the output of  `rpm -ql policycoreutils-python-utils-3.4-4.el9.noarch` if thats what you are looking for.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε thanks, i guess i was missing community.general. it seems to work now. https://github.com/linux-system-roles/selinux mentions the requiements for selinux.. I am not sure why do we have to install these separatly. it should be installed with ansible by default